# laravel file manager Standalone button file path to input

Tags: javascript, laravel

I install laravel file manager successfully but I can't path the file name to the input it's don't clickable

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="image_label" class="form-control" name="image" aria-label="Image"
        aria-describedby="button-image">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-image">Select</button>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        document.getElementById('button-image').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            window.open('/laravel-filemanager', 'fm', 'width=1400,height=800');
        });
    });
    // set file link THIS Don't work <-
    function fmSetLink($url) {
        document.getElementById('image_label').value = $url;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `fmSetLink` function?

Comment: @Saly3301  I just follow this article  https://github.com/alexusmai/laravel-file-manager/blob/master/docs/integration.md#standalone-button

Comment: Not literally, the url is `'/file-manager/fm-button'` there

Comment: when I use this URL give me error in URL I used this instead  '/laravel-filemanager'

Comment: @Saly3301 
404
Not Found

Comment: Never say "error" on Stack Overflow, **ALWAYS** write what the error says

Answer (score 0):

After your function add this : window.fmSetLink = fmSetLink;

Like that

```js
function fmSetLink($url) {

    $('.upload-image-label').val($url)
}

window.fmSetLink = fmSetLink;
```

Works for me